# How To Pause Video and show one UIVIEW and again continue with different Video

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

hi i want to play a video and it pause after a fixed time like 3:12 mm at the same time i want to show one view to user where form is there and when user fill form and submit the button then again play the video.

Comment: You can use timer for that and pause the video after specific time interval.

Comment: i tried can u tell me the step

Comment: Share the code what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Suggestion is use two instance of videoPlayer object. so when pausing first one make it 2nd player to play the video.

And Please use hidden property.

Comment: moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
        [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 98, 310, 156)];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
        
        moviePlayer.fullscreen =YES;
        moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay=YES;
        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;

Comment: moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
        [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 98, 310, 156)];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
        
        moviePlayer.fullscreen =YES;
        moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay=YES;
        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;

Comment: same way create another movieplayer1 and just set hidden. when ever you need load second video and hide the original movie player (ie your code above). still you need any clarification let me know

Comment: i am adding timer in view didload 
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];  and in targetmethod how to pause the movie player